# Unable to install AWS toolkit

Tags: package-install, aws

I am trying to install AWS toolkit for Salesforce on DEV account. I cannot install it as I am getting the following errors.

Your requested install failed. Please try this again.

I am referring https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Amazon_Toolkit document.

So I want to ask you,  Is there any prerequisite to install the toolkit. and How to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check that you are installing the correct package. If you are installing on a developer edition org, use [this](https://login.salesforce.com/?startURL=%2Fpackaging%2FinstallPackage.apexp%3Fp0%3D04t30000000OjsZ) package. If you are installing in production or sandbox, use [this](https://test.salesforce.com/?startURL=%2Fpackaging%2FinstallPackage.apexp%3Fp0%3D04t30000000OjsZ) one. I just tried it again on another fresh developer org and it worked so the package does not have any issues. If you still have issues, it may have to do something to your specific org - log a case with Salesforce support.