# Cannot install AWS Toolkit in sandbox

Tags: package, aws, amazon-s3

I want to install Force.com for AWS through the AppExchange in sandbox. I went through the below link for https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Installing_Force_for_Amazon_Web_Services for step by step guidance.

I even went through this question [Unable to install AWS toolkit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/55198/unable-to-install-aws-toolkit) for solution but the link specified here for sandbox gives error of 'Package Not Found'. Is there any other link for it's installation?

Comment: That web page is 10 years old.  It is probable that the package no longer exists.